# wso2 POM file backslash issue

Tags: maven, maven-3, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to develop an ESB project as CAR file

Everything works as expected locally, but when I commit my code to my SVN then to Jenkins it fails

The reason is the dependency path is using backslash

```
<dependencies>
....
<systemPath>${pom.basedir}\..\target\capp\artifacts/proxy-service\test-proxy\pom.xml</systemPath>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and the maven job fails.

Obviously when I manually correct the pom.xml

```
../workspace/target/capp/artifacts/proxy-service/test-proxy/pom.xml
```

everything works fine, build succeeds and car file is build.

I'm not a JAVA guy myself and I'm new to WS02 as well, so I was wondering if there's a way to amend this behaviour or if I'm simply missing something obvious here.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since there are not answers yet :( I've worked around the issue like this

`gawk '{if ($0 ~ /<systemPath>/) str=gensub(/\\/, "/", "g", $0); else str=$0} {print str}'  pom.xml`

Comment: Why it is not possible for you to use forwardslash in the pom in the first place?